# Session attribute values return null

Tags: java, session

I have set one attribute in session in the first request and retrieve by the second request but its return null while accessing from ios safari browser only.

The requests are served from JSP and getter and setter of attributes are written in Java.

In first request I set

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("KEY","VALUE");
```

In second request I get

```
String key = req.getSession().getAttribute("KEY");
```

the Key is `null` while accessing from IPhone Safari browser.

Please advice.

Comment: we have an implicit session object in jsp, why are you trying to get a new obj and set your attribute

Answer (score 0):

The cookies should be enabled in your browser for session/cookie functionalities to work. Please check privacy setting in the browser.